# Pass an Array over ASIHTTPRequest - POST

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have 2 questions regarding ASIHTTPRequest

1.) Can i send an array through a POST to a web service ?

like;

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc]init];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://t2.com/p.php"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];  
    [request setPostValue:arr forKey:@"peoplearray"];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(done:)];       
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

If you see, I am passing the array like;

`[request setPostValue:arr forKey:@"peoplearray"];`

Is this correct ? if not could you suggest a better working approach ?

Answer (score 3):

That probably won't work as expected. You would have to encode the array to JSON or some other format. I prefer JSON because there are plenty of server-side libraries to work with it. This snippet below requires this [JSON framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/).

```
[request setPostValue:[arr JSONRepresentation] forKey:@"people"];
```

iOS 5 comes with inbuilt JSON classes. Checkout this [article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5) for working with JSON in iOS 5.

Comment: Yes, if you include the linked [JSON framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/).

Answer (score 1):

try this 
It works for me

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:ListPlacesURL];
for (int i =0; i < [placeTagID count]; i++) {
        [request setPostValue:[[data objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ids[%i]",i]];
}
[request startSynchronous];
```